# How to set an IIS Website's Physical Path credentials through Powershell?

Tags: powershell, iis, iis-10

How can I set the IIS 10.0 Website's  Physical Path Credentials through Powershell?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the following Powershell commands :

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='site1']/application[@path='/']/virtualDirectory[@path='/']" -name "userName" -value "jalpa"

Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='site1']/application[@path='/']/virtualDirectory[@path='/']" -name "password" -value "aStrongPassword"

Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='site1']/application[@path='/']/virtualDirectory[@path='/']" -name "logonMethod" -value "ClearText"
```

[image]

Regards,
Jalpa.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the set-webconfiguration cmdlet, which is part of the WebAdministration module.

```
import-module WebAdministration

Set-WebConfiguration -Filter "/system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='Default Web Site']/application[@path='/']/virtualDirectory[@path='/']" -Value @{userName='YourDomain\User'; password='Pa$$word'}
```